# The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier

Tags: xcode, swift, bundle

I try to run my project but i get the following error "The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier."

here my info.plist

[image]

I followed other answer on the question. I don't have any "Ressources" folder inside my project.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Already done ;) my identifier does't bad character, i haven't 'ressources' folder inside my project, my info.plist is link !!

Comment: did you figure it out? i just ran into this issue. one moment i can build, changed 2 lines of code and boom, this stupid error appears

Comment: I restarted my project, I never found the solution ...

Comment: @Multinerd Have you found a solution?

Comment: @KeykoYume clearing derived data fixed it for me iirc

Comment: Thanks @Lilrom for the hint "I don't have any "Ressources" folder inside my project". This was my issue (even though it was located in a dynamic framework which is part of the app target). This helped: https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/12653-the-application-bundle-does-not-contain-a-valid-identifier/

Comment: @HAS I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I solve this problem after I delete all build files by Xcode.
Your build file path at `Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data`

If you didn't change the default path, Your path is like

[image: File Path]

I just deleted all files under `DerivedData`

Comment: Equivalent keyboard shortcut.  cmd + alt + shift + k

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this problem occurred when I manually removed a pod from my file browser in XCode.
In order to fix it, I deleted the associated entry in my podfile, and ran 'pod install' from the terminal.
Additionally, I had to delete the relevant search paths and other references to that pod. And of course I had to clean the project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my app's bundle contained a dash like `com.some-thing.app` so I just changed it to `com.something.app` and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the value for "**Bundle Identifier**" key was missing in Info.plist

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `info.plist` had the wrong encoding format, I still don't know why it changed. So I had to create a new one from Xcode and copy paste all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the project solves my issue. `Product -> Clean`

Answer (score 0):

I was building the wrong target on a device in my case.  I was building the Test target rather than the normal app target.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've added a framework into `Embed Binaries` phase, but it was already in my `Link Frameworks and Binaries` phase, which created a duplicate entry. Once I deleted one of them, this error starting appearing.

To fix it, I've removed the framework from both build phases and added it one more time

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it's caused by a wrong Info.plist in a framework(lack of Bundle identifier and Executable file)

Use `ideviceinstaller -i xx.app` can see the detailed error log.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue trying to run `flutter build ios`, where the errors were related to trying to access WatchOS and TvOS simulators.  For now, not sure how to disable that.

What worked was to run `flutter run`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the framework info.plist lack of Bundle identifier.
use cmake create dynamic framwork misss  Bundle identifier of the info.plist